# JavaScript code gives blank page in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I recently dipped my toe into JavaScript and very quickly ran into some problems. I am trying to run a simple "Hello World" program that is not working. Whenever I open the html file in Safari, I get only a blank page. JavaScript IS enabled in Safari preferences. The file is saved with the .html extension. Here is the code I have written in Sublime Text 2:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> JS Test Page </title>
</head>

    <script type=“text/javascript”>
          document.write(“hello world”); 
    </script>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

If it helps, the path file in the URL is: file:///Users/ME/Desktop/testJS.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your script tag inside the head or body tag.

There was also a problem with the double quotes. They were unicode characters.  Possibly you copied them from a website using a weird font or something instead of typing them and that was messing things up.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> JS Test Page </title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
          document.write("hello world"); 
    </script>
</head>


<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your ***script*** in ***head*** tag.

`Both document.write method should output text into an unready (open) document.`

Read http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy and paste this code?

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
    document.write(“hello world”); 
</script>
```

You error is only because your double quotes, try this code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write("hello world"); 
</script>
```

> and put your script tag inside the body or head tag.

Comment: We wrote almost at same time.

Comment: Can't you delete and up vote mine since I posted 10 min before?

Comment: i will not delete because i really didn't see your answer, it would not be fair with me, but i will up vote for you.